# how do I select a div with class "A" but NOT with class "B"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some divs:

```
<div class="A">"Target"</div>
<div class="A B">"NotMyTarget"</div>
<div class="A C">"NotMyTarget"</div>
<div class="A D">"NotMyTarget"</div>
<div class="A E">"NotMyTarget"</div>
```

Is there a CSS selector that will get me the div containing `Target` but not the divs containing `NotMyTarget`?

Solution must work on IE7, IE8, Safari, Chrome, and Firefox

Edit: So far Nick is the closest.  It's clumsy and I don't like the solution, but at least it works:

```
.A
{
   /* style that all divs will take */
}
div.B 
{
  /* style that will override style .A */
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit poorly formulated. The title makes clear what you want, but the code and question not. The straightforward answer would be: just use `#Target`. As to the answer on the question in the title: CSS3 has a `:not()` selector, but not all browsers do CSS3 yet.

Comment: I like Ron DeVera's solution is more elegant but couldn't get it to work on any browser.  Can any commenters tell me if it absolutely works, and I simply need to work out the little details? (sick today, little patience for this)

Comment: I edited my answer to use `background`, since `outline` doesn't work in older versions of IE. (I usually use `outline` as my default diagnostic CSS, since -- like `background` -- it doesn't modify the layout.) Chris Lively also kindly added a full, working example to my answer.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector to match the `div` that has only one class:

```
div[class=A] {
  background: 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

If you want to select another `div` that has multiple classes, use quotes:

```
div[class="A C"] {
  background: 1px solid #00f;
}
```

Some browsers do not support the attribute selector syntax. As usual, "some browsers" is a euphemism for IE 6 and older.

See also: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attribute.html

**Full example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .A { font-size:22px; }
    .B { font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid blue; }
    .C { color: green; }

    div[class="A"] {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    div[class="A B"] {
      border: 3px solid green;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="A">"Target"</div> 
  <div class="A B">"NotMyTarget"</div> 
  <div class="A C">"NotMyTarget"</div> 
  <div class="A D">"NotMyTarget"</div> 
  <div class="A E">"NotMyTarget"</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2014-02-21:** Four years later, `:not` is now widely available, though verbose in this specific case:

```
.A:not(.B):not(.C):not(.D):not(.E) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in IE 7–8 as specified in the question: http://caniuse.com/#search=:not

Comment: seems very promising, unfortunately I couldn't get this to work.  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong here.  Commenters: this definitely does or does not work (FF, IE7, IE8, Safari)?

Comment: Works fine in FF, Ie8, safari, etc with a strict doctype.

Comment: The `:not()` chain also does not help in cases where you cannot or do not wish to identify which class name to exclude, as long as it is in addition to `A`. The safest bet, then, is with an attribute selector (as long as whitespace and duplicated class names aren't a problem).

Comment: "As usual, "some browsers" is a euphemism for IE 6 and older." is the best thing I've seen all day

Answer (score 54):

```
.A:not(.B) {}
```

But guess who doesn't support that... Indeed, IE<=8.

Comment: ":not" is CSS3. Here is the compatibility chart : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Answer (score 16):

I think the best you can do (until CSS 3) is override the styles in this case with what you don't want from class `A B` in `A`, like this:

```
.A.B { /* Styles */ }
.A { /* Reverse any styling you don't want */ }
```

Comment: Why reverse styling of class A if you can just not include the styling for class A?

Comment: @Verger - Because `class="A B"` matches `.A.B` and `.A` both...but I'm a bit tired, it's possible I have this completely backwards.

Comment: @Nick - True, but `class="B"` only matches `.B` and there is no need for any reversing :) (btw I did not know about the `.A.B` syntax, so thanks for that!)

Comment: @Verger - The OP wants `A` specifically though, so `.B` or anything else would get everything but the element they wanted...definitely backwards to think about that's for sure :)

Comment: The .A.B syntax doesn't work in IE<8. In those browsers IE will only see the last class in the chain - it will apply .A.B to *all* elements with class B

Comment: @Gareth - Yep that's true, but the same result for this question...I'm all ears for a better method, but not sure can get closer on this.  If there is a better method I'd welcome it, then I'd learn something from this as well, which is always a plus.

Comment: @Josh nope, it's correct. Either way would be correct. It's just a matter of if it's shorter to apply or reverse (which side has more undesirable styling than the other) that determines the most succinct way to go. Granted, it's all but moot unless you're supporting ancient browsers at this point anyway.