# Centered Heading With Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm writing a document in sphinx with three main types of elements in it: headings, images and plain text. Occasionally, some elements need to be centered:

```
Heading
=======

.. rst-class:: center

A centered paragraph, followed by non-centered image.

.. image:: /_static/exhibit_a.png

A non-centered paragraph, followed by centered image.

.. image:: /_static/exhibit_b.png
   :class: center
```

The regular text and image get centered just fine because I register a CSS file that looks like this:

```
.center { text-align: center; }
img.center {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

However, the following does not work as intended:

```
.. rst-class: center

===================
A Heading 1 Element
===================

Some generic text
```

The reST `class` (sphinx `rst-class`) directive is only supposed to apply to the element that immediately follows it, but in this case, the whole section becomes center aligned, with everything in it. In this example, `Some generic text` comes out centered, but should be left-aligned. In fact, centering the first heading in the document like this pretty much centers the entire document.

How do I center align a heading in a way that makes it apply only to the `<h1>` tag and not the whole section?

I am using the Read the Docs theme on sphinx 1.8.0, in case that matters.

**Additional Thoughts**

In my case, I need to modify all `<h1>` and `<h2>` instances and no other headings. I know that this is trivial to do in CSS with just

```
h1 h2 { text-align: center; }
```

However, this particular document is part of a much larger project, in which I want to keep all the original styles intact. The only way to do this would be to include my CSS customization only for this one document. Is this a possible alternative?

**Some More Thoughts**

The error is happening because the `center` class is being attached to the `<div>` surrounding the whole section, not the`<h1>` tag. However, I'd like to be able to allow some divs (like extended lines) to be allowed to have the `center` class. Just not divs with a `section` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to unselect the `<div>` element containing the sections I want and to select the headings immediately beneath it in the CSS:

```
.center:not(.section), .center>h1, .center>h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This unselects the outer-level div with a `section` class, but centers the headings underneath it. `:not` appears to be a CSS3 feature not supported on IE8, but that doesn't bother me at all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2482475/2988730

Using `.center>h1` instead of `.center h1` ensures that I only get the exact headings I label, instead of all the nested ones as well. While the latter is temptingly convenient, I will run into problems if I use it, guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the reST markup of `.. rst-class: center`, try combining the CSS selectors, like so:

```
.center h1,
.center h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thus only `h1` and `h2` in the documentation will be centered.

Comment: But I want *some* div / p elements to be centered, just not the whole section.

Comment: I've added another appendix to the question.

Comment: I've posted an answer based heavily on yours.